# Specific solution of wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

$u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0$,  $0<x<1, t>0$,
$u(x,0)=0,  u_t(x,0)=1$, $0\leq x\leq 1$,
$u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0$, $t\geq 0$.

My attempt:
Separation of variables. $c^2 \frac{X''}{X} = \frac{T''}{T}=\lambda$

case i: $\lambda=0$. So $X=c_1x+c_2$, $T=c_3t+c_4$. $u(x,0)=u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0 \implies X=0$. Not possible

case ii: $\lambda>0$. $X=c_1 \exp(\frac{\sqrt{\lambda}}{c}x) + c_2 \exp(\frac{-\sqrt{\lambda}}{c}x)$. $T=c_3 \exp(\sqrt{\lambda}t) + c_4 \exp(-\sqrt{\lambda}t)$. $u(x,0)=u(0,t)=0 \implies X=2c_1\sinh(\frac{\sqrt{\lambda}}{c}x), T= 2c_3\sinh(-\sqrt{\lambda}t)$
$u(1,t)=0 \implies \sinh(\frac{\sqrt{\lambda}}{c}x) = 0$. not possible.

case iii: $\lambda<0$

$X=c_1\sin(\frac{\sqrt{-\lambda}}{c}x) + c_2\cos(\frac{\sqrt{-\lambda}}{c}x)$, $T=c_3\sin(\sqrt{-\lambda}t) +c_4\cos(\sqrt{-\lambda}t)$. $u(x,0)=u(0,t)=0 \implies X=c_1\sin(\frac{\sqrt{-\lambda}}{c}x), T=c_3\sin(\sqrt{-\lambda}t).$ $u(1,t)=0 \implies \sin(\frac{\sqrt{-\lambda}}{c}) = 0 \implies \sqrt{-\lambda} = cn\pi$. $u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} d_n \sin(n\pi x)\sin(cn \pi t)$. $u_t(x,0)=1 \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} cn\pi d_n \sin(n\pi x) =1$.

I don't know how to solve for $d_n$ in $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} cn\pi d_n \sin(n\pi x) =1$. Fourier series probably isn't applicable.

Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Fourier series is applicable.

Comment: @messenger please elaborate. The Fourier expansion of 1 gives just the constant term. $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms don't appear. Thanks.

Comment: You are seeking the sine series expansion of 1, not the full Fourier expansion. (You may need to look up the concepts of Fourier sine series and cosine series, and how they relate to the full Fourier series.)

Comment: @messenger Thanks to your comment, I realised one has to apply Fourier sine series to $f(x)=\begin{cases}  1 & x>0 \\ 0 & x=0 \\ -1 & x<0 \end{cases}$ because fourier sine series requires odd $f$.